# Traceview for Android Market applications

Tags: android, security

I have been using Traceview to improve some of my Android program. The problem is that I want to monitor some program that I've downloaded from Android Market.
I've checked Android developer main page but it seems that you have to add these lines in order to get traceview traces:

Debug.startMethodTracing("calc");

Debug.stopMethodTracing();

For example I'd like to monitor any game downloaded from Android market and see how many resources consume and which functions is calling to set a training data for a normal behavior pattern in IDS. I'm not sure if this is possible with ADB tool.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible - market apps are signed, so you can't just insert random code.